# Sending an mp4 video over the network with avconv command to a raspberry pi in a piwall videowall

Tags: raspberry-pi, avconv, omxplayer

I would like to send an mp4 video from a raspbery pi to another raspberry-pi (in order to build a piwall) but the command I am using for sending a video stream (tested with correct outcome on other devices) doesn't work.

Details:
I am using the avconv command from libav.org to send an mp4 video from a "master raspberry pi" through the network to my "slave raspberry pi". The raspberry pi (which is receiving the video) has the Raspbian Jessie Operating System on it. The goal of my experiment is to use the pwomxplayer command to display the video received on the "slave raspberry pi".

The full command i am using for sending the mp4 video stream is as follows:
avconv -re -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -f h264 -an udp://224.0.0.1:1234
(works when sending to my raspberry pi from my dell laptop)

It is interesting to note that when using the pre-mentioned avconv command on my dell laptop which has an intel processor and debian OS installed, the video stream is sent properly. However, the same command doesn't work when sending the video stream from a raspberry pi which has an arm processor and raspbian OS installed.
I wonder why this is!

Am I right in thinking the arm processor is not interpreting my command avconv as well as the intel processor? Or is it more a question of architecture? Or is my avconv command syntax incorrect?

Thank you for your help!

More info:
Ip address of master raspberry pi: 192.168.72.10
Ip address of slave raspberry pi: 192.168.72.11
I am using the route add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 224.0.0.0 eth0 command on master pi to send the video stream to all laptops connected to my ethernet port.
The following command works for files ending in .h264:
avconv -re -i input.h264 -vcodec libx264 -f h264 -an udp://224.0.0.1:1234
(but I would like to send .mp4 files encoded with h264 not just .h264 files)

Edit:
Here is the output of the avconv command both on the intel computer as piwall master and the raspberry pi as piwall master:

[avconv working on dell tower piwall master in ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhUv6.jpg)

[avconv NOT working on raspberry pi piwall master in raspbian Jessie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7IGh.jpg)

We are using the same video file for both attempts ; The raspberry pi says we are over the MB limit and doesn't send anything.

Comment: The avconv output would probably give you the annswer.

Comment: @szatmary, I have uploaded the output of both commands. Intel seems to be using ffmpeg when I run avconv command.